# Getting "invalid create index error" on java prepared statement call but identical statement works in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, database, oracle, indexing

I am running the following create index call in a prepared statement:

```
CREATE INDEX tmplocind_1
 ON TMPLOCATION( country_name );

 CREATE INDEX tmplocind_2
 ON TMPLOCATION(subdivision_1_name, city_name);

 CREATE INDEX tmplatlngind
 ON TMPLATLNG(geoname_id);
```

When I run this in SQL Developer, the indexes are all created.   But when I submit it as a prepared statement, I get:
ORA-02158: invalid CREATE INDEX option

I have tried taking out the semicolon(s) to no avail.  I don't understand this difference in behavior.

Comment: Could you please add your complete prepared statememt

Comment: preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(part);
                preparedStatement.execute();   part is the above String loaded from a text file

Comment: No, please edit your question (not comments) and show the complete relevant code exactly as it is.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind;  I got around this by removing the semicolons and making three separate calls to the DB; each was able to create an index.